# Searching a directory for specific XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I had a question regarding how to parse and search XML files in a specific directory.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = '/home/user/Desktop'
for FILENAME in os.listdir(path):
    if not FILENAME.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, FILENAME)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
```

Now I need to search all the xml files for a specific name!

Any Help?

Comment: When you say specific, do you mean, the file is named _exactly_ `foo.xml` or is it matching some pattern, like, `foo-date-1.xml`? If it's named _exactly_ `foo.xml` you don't need to search for endwith('.xml'), you can just search for `if filename == os.path.join(path, "foo.xml")

Comment: Sorry. There is specific information in the XML file (the directory has like 700 XML files) that i need to search for.

Comment: What exactly do you want to find in file? You can use even regex because xml file is just another text file if the structure have no meaning for solution.